# Stop sending e-mails with the same job offers

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Stack Overflow is sending e-mails with the same job offers over and over…

The e-mail starts with:

> We found new jobs that match your interests!

but they are not new at all…

My suggestion is to remember which were already sent and avoid repetition.

Comment: Or at the least change the wording to be more accurate

Comment: @KevinB "We're not sure if you saw the previous job offers, so we're sending them again, just in case!"

Comment: Hmmm, we shouldn't be; looks like a bug here

Comment: I'm literally getting emails every day with the same 'new' jobs - totally devalues SE Jobs for me :|

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, bug found; you were subscribed to 'All New Jobs' which incorrectly used the 'matches' sort order. When the matches sort order is used with an empty search it skips querying the Elastic index for performance reasons and hits the cache instead. Unfortunately the 'we sent you this before' filtering happens in Elastic.

I've just pushed a fix to prod that makes things happen in the right place and we'll no longer send you dupes. Sorry about that and thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Hello! I just started seeing the same problem--I am receiving the same Job Alert with the same 2 jobs every day. Did you guys have a regression of some sort?

Comment: @DawnPaladin see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349358/how-to-stop-receiving-multiple-jobs-emails-with-identical-content