# How to stop receiving multiple Jobs Emails with identical content

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, email

I like receiving emails with listing jobs that match my criteria. Even though the matches are not really what I'd call accurate, I can easily scan them for things I might like. However, over the last few days I am getting multiple emails a day with the exact same set of jobs listings. Is there a way I can control this short of stopping all emails? Otherwise, can you hash them, or something, and not send me duplicate emails?

And multiple emails a day is too many, how do I limit it to 1 or 2 a week?

Comment: I mostly get 1 a day, but the content is entirely duplicated. And the weekly summary doesnt seem to allow filters like location

Comment: Looking into this now; there's something not right here

Comment: @ste-fu there's changes on the way for this confusing (and only slightly differing) set of emails. Not sure of the scope just yet, but the weekly email will likely filter by your match prefs

Comment: @DeanWard Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gah, this is my fault. We have an abstract syntax tree (AST) representing a job search query that I made immutable last week. We have a substantial set of unit tests for the tree and the visitors that are used to transform it along the way so I thought I was covered.

*However*, the one damn visitor that doesn't have a test is also the one responsible for telling the search engine what jobs to ignore. Notably jobs that you've previously applied to and ones that we sent you before. And, unfortunately, it's also the only one that I didn't tweak to mutate it's local copy of the tree.

So, I've added a unit test, fixed the underlying code and verified that we have tests for all the other transforming visitors and that they function correctly.

We also had a marked increase in the number of alerts sent in the past couple of days because of this issue so I'm also adding an alert that tells us in chat when the number of alerts sent is substantially above what we expect.

That code is now pushed to production. My sincere apologies for the inconvenience and thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Hey, Dean, thanks! The duplicates stopped right when you posted this, but I didn't get back to it because I didn't notice it because I stopped getting duplicates! So, it works, thanks!!