# "New jobs on Stack Overflow" email no longer just new jobs

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I have a job alert set up to send me daily email messages with new Remote Contract listings.

I'm used to getting an email every couple of days with one or two brand-new listings (created in the last 24h), but since yesterday(? or a couple days ago) I'm getting messages every day now with the same 10 listings.

Possible root cause: [How to stop receiving multiple Jobs Emails with identical content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349358/how-to-stop-receiving-multiple-jobs-emails-with-identical-content)? If so, feel free to mark as duplicate.