# I just received 25 duplicate emails at once from SO Jobs

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, email

I received 25 legit but duplicate emails in the same minute from StackOverflow jobs.

This is not a Job Alerts email, I've never been subscribed to job alerts.

Staff are welcome to contact me in private of they would like more details, although I'd ask they limit it to a single email not 25

Comment: This has happened before: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349358/how-to-stop-receiving-multiple-jobs-emails-with-identical-content

Comment: Is this just job alerts, a single company sending multiple emails, etc... as @gparyani points out the job alert (results) email repeating itself several times in a day has happened before if it is that.

Comment: Well.... one of our clients got about 800 (!) duplicate emails once due to a bug that I had in my code (lacked sanity check of "next time to send" variable, when it was null, it just kept sending in a loop). So consider yourself lucky. :D

Comment: @Shadow that is nothing compared to a "reply all" debacle we had at our uni once... Some student figured out how to send an email to something along the lines of `students@school.nl`

Comment: @Cerbrus oh wow.... lol. What did he send? What happened to him when caught?

Comment: Some kind of survey. That student wasn’t reprimanded, as it was the IT department’s failure. However, there were a lot of other students that thought it was funny to put people’s phone numbers and other PII in the emails. And there were some severe threats.  Those students were all suspended for 1-2 weeks.

Comment: @Cerbrus and that's why we can't have nice things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We were running a clean-up task on the table that we use for queuing emails and the scheduled task that actually sends emails timed out while updating whether it sent the email or not. That task runs once a minute and it timed out several times, resulting in duplicate emails being relayed to SendGrid because it didn't think it had sent them yet.

Sorry for the inconvenience here, I've logged a bug to retry the update in the event of a timeout to (hopefully, retries can be fun when everything is on fire) stop this happening again.